# Confusion about depletion layer in pn-junction?

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics

> Here: [external link](http://physicsgalaxy.com/lectures/1/50/802/Introduction%20to%20to%20PN%20Junction)
>
> Seek: around (2:53)

Since n-type and more electrons than p-type and vice versa for holes, they diffuse and in the process neutralize in the central region. How is the $\vec E$ produced due to neutral lattice? In p-type we have excess holes (still) and in other excess electrons so a test charge(conventionally, positive) will move towards n-type(attraction to electrons and repulsion form holes), so Electric field will be form p to n; but there are other equal posotive and negative chargess too (the donor nuclei) which give (after analyzing) an opposite electric field, so why do the field is from p to n?

Comment: Equilibrium is obtained when the Fermi energies on both sides are the same.  Since they are clearly different in n-type vs p-type, the built-in potential is such that qV equal the difference in Fermi energies. This potential is the result of electrostatics of the dopant atoms in the host.  Whether the carriers diffuse and recombine, or are parted like the Red Sea before Moses, is irrelevant to what the final equilibrium state looks like.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since n-type and[have] more electrons than p-type and vice versa for holes, they diffuse and in the process neutralize in the central region.

You have misunderstood things. A diode as a whole is neutral but not the p and n regions across the depletion layer. The video that you've linked is partially technically incorrect, But the inaccuracy is altogether different from your doubt. It correctly says that n-type and p-type regions are charged at 3:56 with the following words:

> ...An Electric field is established by negative ions [present] in the p side and positive ions [present] on[in] the n side...

Both the p and n sides are initially neutral before the diffusion current starts. After the diffusion current starts, the holes from p side starts moving towards the n side. These holes carry a positive charge. So these will make the n region positively charged. Similarly, the electron moves from the n side towards the p side. Since electrons are negatively charged particles, they will make the p region negatively charged. Following is a figure of an ideal step junction diode, taken from wikipedea:
[image]

It is clear that the Electric field is from n to p. Note that the diffusion occurs because of the abrupt variation in the density of charge carriers across the depletion layer.

Now comes the technical mistakes in that video.

1. There isn't any neutral region in the depletion region. there is a plane of 0 thickness which is electrically neutral, as is clear from the picture above.
2. The diffusion current never stops. It would stop only when the concentration gradient would have ceased to exist -- but this never happens. As soon as the diffusion current starts, opposite  charges start to build on both the sides creating an Electric field. Since the material is semiconductor, it has charge carriers in its whole body at room temperature. Even if some charge carriers get combine to neutralise each other, due to temperature new electron-hole pairs will be generated. The misconception that might develop is that the potential difference will stop the diffusion current altogether. Diffusion current consists of the charge carriers moving at high speeds because of their thermal energies. So, the Electric field can't stop the diffusion current, then what does happen next, do the charges keep piling up on p and n sides. No! the drift current comes into picture. As you know the diffusion current is only due to majority carriers, and can't be stopped. but there are minority carriers too. the potential difference across the depletion layer causes the minority carriers to move and create the drift current. When the steady-state reaches, the drift current becomes equal to the diffusion current. The hole-drift current is given by $J_p= qp\mu_p E$ and the hole-diffusion current is given by $qD_p \frac{dp}{dx}$, The expresions for electron-drift and electron-diffusion currents are similar, with the subscript being $n$. If you want I can add references and mathematical proves to vindicate my assertions.

Comment: I couldn't find nothing wrong at around 2:56. The video is technically incorrect after 3:40, when it says that there is some neutral region inside the depletion region. Then it incorrectly claims that the no further flow of charge carriers take place.